Why would pandas not show warnings on one machine, but does on another?
My partner and I are running the same script one two machines. My partner is seeing a warning that I am not seeing.
We are both using PyCharm, have checked the version of every single package, and have the same version of windows. Is there any other reason my machine is not showing a warning?
It is the pandas warning 'Setting with copy', but I am less concerned about fixing the warning. I am more concerned with my machine did not give me the warning.
Here is the script:
for inncode in all_properties['inncode'].unique():
    star_data['inncode'] = inncode 


Warning:
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer, col_indexer] =
value instead


This kind of warnings should be visible on both computers. Also I would suggest to consider fixing the warning, otherwise two separate dataframe variables become linked and changes in first dataset may affect data in the second.
Problem is in how star_data was initiated. Most probably it was created as a filter/slice from another dataset. Basically you did something like this:
star_data = DF.loc[DF['colname'] == x]
In this case star_data is referring to the memory allocated by DF. This is because dataframe slices are mutable objects and thus they actually points to the original data in DF. And thus changing values in star_data may potentially change values in DF as well.
To fix this you should explicitly state that star_data should be created as a separate object:
star_data = df.loc[df['colname'] == x].copy(deep=True)
